# Generic Comparable with "Comparison method violating its general contract"

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparator, comparable

I have this generic method which sorts a `Map` by value:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue(Map<K, V> map) {
    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Stream<Map.Entry<K, V>> st = map.entrySet().stream();
    st.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).forEachOrdered(e -> result.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    return result;
}
```

I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`. I cannot understand how the contract is violated. Also, how can I make it work?

Comment: We have no way of knowing.  What that error is telling you is that your `V` type implements `compareTo` incorrectly.  You haven't told us what your `V` type is or how its `compareTo` works.  There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us, the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: The problem lies in the `compareTo` method on your `V` class. The most usual case is that your relationship isn't transitive, for example miscomparing nulls or having `a == b` and `b == c` but `a != c`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Oh. That actually... answers my question. While I was trying to pinpoint the mistake in above code I didn't look where I was supposed to look. I did find the guilty `compareTo`. I wouldn't vote to close this question though - I can see it being helpful for someone.